# How can I implement this function with JSON?

Tags: node.js, json, request

```
POST http://localhost:5000/api/users/register-user{
  {
    body: {
      "username": "testing",
      "email": "testing@gmail.com",
      "passwort": "testing"
    }
  }
}
```

Normally I POST via Postman but I want to write a .http file where I can see it directly with Visual Studio Code.

Has anybody an idea how I can do that?

Thanks

Comment: take your pick
https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios or https://github.com/request/request or native https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http

Comment: Thanks dear. It helps. Do you know how I can request Header content like Authorization ?